# Events of a given user with Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a mobile application which will feature Facebook events feed, events coming from some FB pages.

I was wondering if there is any way of getting events of a given person using Facebook Graph API? I know there's a way of getting as I mentioned pages events (with "pageid"/events/attending/?access_token) and "my" events (when I am the logged user) but is there any way of getting public events created by a specific user (provided I know their UserId)? I am using PHP for my server side.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a little work to get all the events created by a user.

First call the /accounts endpoint with the user id and access token to get a list of pages that user administers as well as tokens for accessing them (this will include the users home page).

Getting events for the userId will also give you all the events that the user has created in any of their groups.

Now call the /events endpoint for each of these pages. Each call will return a list of events for a page that you'll have to filter and aggregate together.

To filter, you'll call the /event endpoint for each of the above page events so that you can determine that the event for a page was actually created by that user (check the owner field).

Easy peasy!